# Killing cv2 read process after N time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm desperate.

My code reads nframe in videos, sometimes the code just stop for no reason, and no error.
So I decided to somehow raise an error.
The thing is, the code does raise an error, but it ignores it for some reason, and just works as normal.

*Ive provided a code block on which exactly the same method works.

handler:

```
def handler(signum,frame):
  print("error") ## This is printed
  raise Exception('time out') ## I guess this is getting raised
```

Code part i want to wrap:

```
for i in range(0,int(frame_count), nframe): # basicly loads every nframe from the video

   try:
      frame = video.set(1,i)
      signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM), handler)
      signal.alarm(1) # At this point, the 'handler' did raise the error, but it did not kill this 'try' block.

      _n,frame = video.read() # This line sometimes gets for infinit amount of time, and i want to wrap it

   except Exception as e:
      print('test') # Code does not get here, yet the 'handler' does raise an exception
      raise e

   # Here i need to return False, or rise an error, but the code just does not get here.
```

An example where exactly the same method will work:

```
import signal
import time

def handler(signum, frame):
   raise Exception('time out')

def function():
   try:
      signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,handler)
      signal.alarm(5) # 5 seconds till raise
      time.sleep(10) # does not get here, an Exception is raised after 5 seconds

   except Exception as e:
      raise e # This will indeed work
```

Comment: You're ignoring the first return value of `video.read()` (called `_n` here). Are you sure that it's not just returning `False` there, and it's your own code that's looping forever? You usually want to exit the loop when that value is `False`: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Comment: Yes, the problem is not the looping over and over, The code indeed runs.
I will try this method, problem is, I'm guessing that the _ is sometimes just not returning, and the code gets stuck.

I tried it with an indicator, and printed each iteration, but it just freeze in one iteration.. there is no indication after that, its just taking infinite time to read the image or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `read()` call is blocked somewhere inside C code. The signal handler runs, puts an exception into the Python interpreter somewhere, but the exception isn't handled until the Python interpreter regains control. This is a limitation [documented in the `signal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers):

> A long-running calculation implemented purely in C (such as regular expression matching on a large body of text) may run uninterrupted for an arbitrary amount of time, regardless of any signals received. The Python signal handlers will be called when the calculation finishes.

One possible workaround is to read frames on a separate process using the `multiprocessing` module, and return them to the main process using a `multiprocessing.Queue` (from which you can `get` with a timeout). However, there will be extra overhead in sending the frames between processes.

Another approach might be to try and avoid the root of the problem. OpenCV has different video backends (V4L, GStreamer, ffmpeg, ...); one of them might work where another doesn't. Using the second argument to the `VideoCapture` constructor, you can indicate a preference for which backend to use:

```
cv.VideoCapture(..., cv.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294da77ab1fe260fd182f8ec7655fab27a31d) for the full list of backends. Depending on your platform and OpenCV build, not all of them will be available.

Comment: Great, Thanks! will try these methods.